# How to integrate payment processing with GWT / GAE based app?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, payment-processing

I have a GWT based app, which is deployed on Google App Engine for Java. The app uses Google Accounts based authentication. I'm maintaining basic user information such as email id (from Google Accounts), last login date etc. in the GAE datastore. The access to the website is free. Anyone can use it using his/her Google Account.

Going forward, I would like to make it a paid service. However, I have zero experience with setting up and operating an e-commerce website. So my question may be a bit vague. I need some guidance on how to go about it.

Here are some of my requirements (but I'm flexible on the exact implementation):

1. Offer 2 different types of account - free and premium.
2. I do not want to maintain any credit card related information in my system. I would also prefer to not maintain an elaborate user database.
3. When a user first logs in, he/she automatically gets a free account.
4. User has to "upgrade" to a premium account to access all features of the application.
5. User has to pay a one-time fee to upgrade.

Given this information, I have the following questions:

1. Is GAE suited for my requirements?
2. Which payment gateway (Paypal, Google Checkout etc.) would be most suitable for my requirements?
3. What level of integration is required between my app and the Payment gateway? I would like to maintain minimal user information in my app. I want to focus on my application development and want to spend minimal effort on user administration.
4. Would I need to implement a custom authentication mechanism or continue to use Google Accounts or another OpenID based authentication?
5. What other things do I need to consider?

I'll appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, there's absolutely no reason why you wouldn't be able to keep the current application and its account management. You can extend your user account with an account type field that stores whether the user is a paying customer or not. If you need to send invoices, also store the users contact information (Paypal will send this to you together with payment receipts)

As far as specific payment providers is concerned. I only have practical hands-on experience with PayPal. I would not use them again for a few reasons:

- Their APIs are not very well documented and some of the documentation is wrong (or out-of-date).
- If you're a small player, support is mostly via the forums. So basically this means you're on your own.
- Some of the APIs have serious gaping holes and missing functionality (for instance, you can create subscriptions, but not cancel them if you're using the standard payments APIs.
- Outside of the US and a few lucky countries, the advanced APIs are not available. So you're stuck with implementing a IPN listener servlet, while it would much more preferable to pull the information when needed.

All existing PayPal Java libraries I have found use the Pro features that are not available to most of the users. Because I couldn't find it anywhere else, I have created and open sourced my own [IPN servlet](http://www.streamhead.com/java-paypal-ipn-servlet/) but it is very unfinished. If there is a demand for it, I'd be willing to improve it, just let me know.

What this IPN servlet does is listen to incoming PayPal messages. For instance, if a user subscribes, you'll get a message. If a user is billed (for instance on a monthly cycle), you'll get a message. If a user cancels his subscription you'll get a message. Those message allow you to maintain the account type of the user.

If I'd do it again, I would probably use a more advanced and higher level subscription API, such as [Spreedly](http://www.spreedly.com/info/integration). I've heard some good things about the API and they are pretty affordable. I have no actual experience with Spreedly, so this is not an endorsement.

Comment: @Peter - I really appreciate your follow-up on my comment on your blog. I have gone through all the posts related to Paypal on your blog and found them to be useful. I also went through the PaypalX GAE Toolkit and found the samples relevant. But my basic doubt - why use Adaptive Payment API over standard button with redirect - still remains. See my comment below the previous answer (above). Please share your thoughts if you get a chance. Either way I think I'll be using your IPN Servlet. So any improvements that you do would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I did some initial research on the various APIs, but since I can only use the standard one, I haven't fully investigated any others. The Adaptive Payments API is a full web service. If you use that one, there's no need for redirects or callback IPN servlets. It will make your code cleaner and easier. As far as I know, the Adaptive Payments one is also the most modern of the PayPal APIs. Keep in mind that it might cost you a little. If you want to the standard API, but require a little more leeway, check out the Express Checkout API.[See NVP library](http://paypal-nvp.sourceforge.net/index.htm)

Comment: I'm still getting familiar with Paypal terminology. 1. What do you mean by 'standard one'? 2. Why can't I use Website Payment Standard Button? Is that what you mean by standard? 3. Regarding Adaptive Payments API, have you looked at the samples provided by Paypalx GAE Toolkit? They are using redirect and IPN Servlet [click here](http://pp-pymt-reconciler.appspot.com). I feel that "Pay" API should fit the bill for me. 4. Is there a cost associated with using Adaptive Payments? I didn't see any info on that. Can you clarify this? I'll read more on Express Checkout and the NVP library. Thanks.

Comment: 1. there is a "pro" and a "standard" payments API. Pro offers a richer API. 2. You can use the buttons, they just point to a payment screen on the PayPal servers. 3. I have not investigated the PayPal X toolkit as I'm based in Belgium where I cannot use the Adaptive Payments API. I believe you can combine the IPN servlet with any payment form or API. Basically, PayPal will send status updates to the servlet. 4. Again, I haven't looked into this further since I can't use it, but I believe you need a more expensive account type to be able to use Adaptive Payments

Comment: Things are getting clearer now. I found [this thread](https://www.x.com/thread/48291) which indicates that there are no special fees for using Adaptive APIs. At this point, I'm inclined towards using a simple button, but if that doesn't work out for any reason, then I'll try to use Adaptive APIs. In both the cases, I'll probably use your IPN Servlet. Now I have 2 questions. 1. What kind of updates does your IPN Servlet need (you said it's unfinished)? 2. If I use a button, can I pass the user_id as "custom" parameter and get that back in IPN to identify the user in my system? Thanks.

Comment: 1. There are no functional issues. But it is pretty rough: First, it currently only extracts the fields I need. It's trivial to extend this though. Second, with what I know now, I'd like to take a second look at the architecture. And last, I really need to get this Mavenized and into a Maven repository for easy integration. 2. Yes, you just add the custom field as a hidden field to the button. Keep in mind that, for security reasons, you might not want to expose the user id (but use a one-time key).

Comment: Sure, got it. I'm now going to start prototyping this in the Sandbox environment and see how it works. It would be great if you enhance your Servlet. In the meanwhile, I'm going to use the version you already have. I'll keep in touch (here and on your blog). Thanks so much for patiently responding to all my questions.

Answer (score 1):

GAE supports this kind of applications without any particular problem; if your language of choice is Java, I would pick Paypal with this [toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/paypalx-gae-toolkit/) because Google Checkout Java API [does not seem to work very well](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/72ac2d4490bcc11d) on GAE.

You would need an **Authorization** mechanism to check what your users are allowed to do based on their permissions.
Basically you would need the following things:

1. A flag `membership` status that indicates if a user is Premium or not; this should be set after the payment notification
2. An authorization system to check if, reading the `membership` flag value
   , a given Web Handler can be consumed by the current user

Have a look to [this](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/02/spring-security-in-google-app-engine/) great Spring Security tutorial; it covers:

- Authentication using Google Accounts.
- Setup access-control restrictions based on the roles assigned to users.

Comment: Hello systempuntoout, thanks for your response. It has taken me one step forward. I had already seen the Spring Security tutorial, but I'm not sure whether it's appropriate for my simple app which has only 2 roles (excluding the ADMIN role, which is automatically provided by the app engine). I have 2 questions at this point. 1. Can I not manage authorization programmatically (to start with) if my app is pretty simple? Let me know if I'm missing something. I'm posting the second question in a separate comment.

Comment: 2. I need to study Paypal X API in more detail, but at this point, I'm not able to figure out how the Google Accounts Id (email Id) would tie back to the Paypal Id of the user. My understanding is this - A new user logs into my app. The user clicks an "Upgrade Now" link in the app. This link takes the user to Paypal where user makes the payment. Paypal sends a notification of a successful payment back to my app. The app updates the user role to PREMIUM. If this is how it would work, then how would the request from my app to Paypal, and the response from Paypal identify the user? Thanks.

Comment: 1. you can code a decorator or a simple method that just checks the Membership flag 2. You should use the user_id to identify the user and not the email (that could change)

Comment: On #2, I can use user_id to identify the user but my doubt still remains. Let me explain again. Let's say user1 clicks on "Upgrade Now", goes to Paypal, uses an email address xyz@hotmail.com to make the payment, and I get the transaction details from Paypal telling that a person with email id xyz@hotmail.com has made the payment. Now how would I know that the email address xyz@hotmail.com belongs to user1? The user may not have pre-registered his/her Paypal user id in my app. Thanks.

Comment: @DFB Have you studied the Paypal X API? Are you sure that you can pass an additional user_ID parameter to the Paypal call? In this way you could associate the callback to a specific user.

Comment: I have been reading various Paypal docs, but they have so many different APIs. I'm not sure which one is suited for my requirement. I really want to keep it simple - user clicks a button, makes a one-time payment on the Paypal website, my app get an IPN and updates the user database. That's all. Which API should I look at? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Paypal X seems to offer only the Adaptive Payments, have a look to it.

Comment: It's not easy, but possible. If you are using the standard buttons, you can add a custom field. This will allow you to link the user account in your application to the payment. However, make sure you also store the subscriber id (subscr_id), because recurring payments will no longer have this custom field.

Comment: I read through the Adaptive API Guide, but just can't figure out one basic thing. Why do I need to use the API? Why can't I use Website Payment Standard (redirect with standard button) as described [here](http://www.ridgesolutions.ie/Hooking_up_GAE_and_Paypal.pdf). If I don't intend to use subscriptions / recurring payments, and all I need is one-time payment, then what does the Adaptive Payment API buy me? Sorry if this question sounds too elementary. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need subscription based billing with free trials, coupons, plan upgrades/downgrades, Dunning management and a whole lot more then take a look at [Recurly](http://www.recurly.com).

You can choose to have customers maintain their billing information on pages hosted by [Recurly](http://www.recurly.com), or use their Transparent POST API to post billing info to their servers from a page in your GAE app - both solutions avoid passing sensitive credit card data through your servers, which makes PCI compliance easy.

The Java API is not fully developed but it's easy to build out for your specific requirements using JAXB. I do not have my code wrapped into an open source project but would be willing to share snippets.

Comment: Hello Rori, at this point I have no plans to make it a subscription based service. This is the first time I'm trying to do such a thing. So, I'm taking this as a pilot project. I don't want to sign-up for a third party service that comes with its own subscription fee. But I appreciate your help. I'll keep your suggestion in mind for my future projects. Thanks.